# Stuck Loops/ iteration [C sharp]

Tags: c#, console

I am trying to make a loop that will add all the entered numbers and display the sum of all the entered numbers when I type "ok". If you could give me a way to do it that would be great. Thank you.

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        {
            int sum = 0;

            while (true) {

                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number: \n");
                int num;
                if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out num))
                {
                    {
                        if (num == 0)
                        {
                            break;
                            sum += num;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (Convert.ToString(num) == "ok")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Sum is " + sum);
                    break;
                }
           }
        }

     }


  }

}
```

Comment: think about it. you are reading a string - then parse it to a number. then you try to convert that number back to a string and hope that somehow, there's a number that creates the string "ok"? 1) no. numbers are numeric. no letters, generally. 2) why don't you just store what you read with `Console.ReadLine()` in a variable and test _that_?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution, please read up on C# fundamentals before copy pasting.

```cs
// Setup our variables
string input;
var total = 0;

// Begin a loop running forever
do
{
    // Get the user input as a string - the code has no idea it is a number at this point
    Console.Write("Input a number: ");
    input = Console.ReadLine();

    // See if we can parse the string into a number, this function returns a boolean, hence if the string is an int, the `total += value` block is executed
    if (int.TryParse(input, out var value))
    {
        total += value;
    }
    else if (input.ToLower() != "ok")
    {
        // If the input string is not an int, and the input is not "ok" then, let them know their input was not a number
        Console.WriteLine("Please input a number...");
    }
    else
    {
        // The input string was not an int, but it was the string "ok", therefore break out of this loop
        break;
    }
} while (true);

// After breaking out of the loop, print the total
Console.WriteLine(total);
```

Comment: a solution without an _explanation_ is not _actually_ helpful to someone still learning.

Comment: True, I have added comments going through the basic logic

Comment: @Luke technically if an answer has helped it should be upvoted. If an answer is the one the OP ends up using, it should be checked.. subtle difference being any number of answers may help and hence be upvoted but only one can be declared as the one the OP went with.. When someone answers my question I both upvote and check because it's helpful and I picked it